# sscanf adding in 0's to my string

Tags: c, scanf

I'm writing some c code for an assembler used for a virtual computer designed for our text book. The point is to get the binary output to look the same as it does after running assembly through the program that accompanies the text book. I was on the last instruction to convert to binary, BR (for branch), and was having some trouble with sscanf. The function is,

```
char* br(char* line) {
int num, i, l, n = 0, z = 0, p = 0;
char bin[17] = "0000";
char word[20], arg1[20];

sscanf(line, "%S%S", word, arg1);
l = strlen(word);
for (i = 2; i < l; i++) {
    if (word[i] == 'N') {
        n = 1;
    } else if (word[i] == 'Z') {
        z = 1;
    } else if (word[i] == 'P') {
        p = 1;
    }
}
bin[4] = n + '0';
bin[5] = z + '0';
bin[6] = p + '0';

while (label[i] != 0) {
    if (strcmp(label[i], arg1) == 0) {
        num = address[i] - currentAddress - 1;
        decToBinary(num, arg1);
        break;
    }
    i++;
}

for (i = 7; i < 16; i++) {
    bin[i] = arg1[i];
}
return bin;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that sscanf is adding 0's between every character placed in word and arg1 so they are terminated. The incoming string "BRZP START" is broken into "B" for word and "S" for arg1 respectively. I've used sscanf in this way a bunch already and don't know why its not working now.

Comment: Have you tried it with a space between `%s %s`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) for sscanf it seems that %S (capital S) does not really mean anything (based off the printf man page, it looks as if it is equivalent to "ls", which reads wide characters from the string, but should not be used. When a string of short characters is converted to a string of long characters, every second character will seem to equal zero). Try this:

```
sscanf(line, "%s%s", word, arg1);
```

Comment: The OP used `"%S%S"` and your solution wisely suggests to use `%s` instead of `%S`.  But the added space is not needed.  `%s`  all ready skips leading whitespace.  `"%s%s"` is closer to OP's style.

Comment: Good suggestion, change made

Comment: Oops! I suggested a no space and used "all ready" when I should use "already".

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the host OS or development platform you're using, but I'm not in the least bit surprised you're getting two bytes for every character considering that `%S` tells `sscanf` to read wide chars in some implementations.  If your input is ASCII, you'll get ASCII chars plus a null byte, just as you're seeing.  The solution is simple: use `%s` not `%S`.